# Laravel. CarbonPeriod. All "unical" months between two dates

Tags: php, laravel

How to make a period with all months between two random dates?
I tried:

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-11-17 23:59:59');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-01-10 00:00:00');

$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 month', $endDate);

foreach($period as $month)
{
    echo '<pre>'.$month->format('Y-m-d').'</pre>';
}
```

but it doesn't include January.

I also tried to use floor():

```
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2021-11-17 23:59:59');
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-01-31 00:00:00');

$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, '1 month', $endDate)->floor();

foreach($period as $month)
{
    echo '<pre>'.$month->format('Y-m-d').'</pre>';
}
```

but it includes February that don't even need.

How to get pure "unical" months between two dates using CarbonPeriod?

For example: **start_date: 2021-11-17 23:59:59** & **end_date: 2022-01-10 00:00:00** -> **11, 12, 01**

Also: **start_date: 2021-11-17 23:59:59** & **end_date: 2022-01-31 00:00:00** -> **11, 12, 01**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `startOfMonth()` and   `endOfMonth()` as below.

```
    $startDate = Carbon::parse('2021-11-17 23:59:59')->startOfMonth();
    $endDate = Carbon::parse('2022-01-10 00:00:00')->endOfMonth();
    
    foreach (CarbonPeriod::create( $startDate, '1 month', $endDate) as $month) {
         echo  $month->format('m') . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Output will be:
11
12
01

Comment: Values of $startDate & $endDate must be saved, but I can clone them and use your solution. 
Thank you.